# Android.widget.linearlayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, runtime-error, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add two LinearLayout in the same row, in the code, but it's show the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Android.widget.linearlayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Tablelayout
```

My code:

```
TableLayout main = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    TableRow tr = null;
    LinearLayout controw = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < llista.size(); i++) {
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        controw = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap resizedbitmap = ImagesResources.getInstance()
                .StringResourceToBitmapResized(getResources(),
                        getPackageName(), llista.get(i).getSrcImatge(),
                        200, 200, true);
        img.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
        textView.setText(list.get(i).getNameList());
        controw.addView(textView);
        controw.addView(img);
        tr.addView(controw);
        tr.addView(controw);
        main.addView(tr);
    }
```

If I add only one LinearLayout it work good, but when I want to add the second LinearLayout it crash.
The function StringResourceToBitmapResized return the correct bitmap.
And the array list has 4 elements.

Thanks

Comment: where is xml file please may be this is LinerLayout (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

Comment: BTW. You cannot add the same view multiple times - `tr.addView(controw); tr.addView(controw);` <- these lines are wrong. One view can be added in one place at the time. You need to create new LinearLayout with new children.

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar thanks for response. I make a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,
I make a mistake I tried to put the table over a linearlayout.
I change the xml declaration from linearlayout to tablelayout.
Sorry